# Mule Requester - Picking same file

Tags: mule

While I am trying to move two files (say File1.txt and File.txt) with the help of MuleRequester. MuleRequester is picking File1 two times. Rather than it should first pick File1 and then File2. Can anyone please help me provide the resolution?
I am using 3.8.0 runtime. have attached snapshot of flow for your ready reference

[image]

Note : Http requester has been used just to make execution user driven.

Comment: What is the size of ur File1.txt? If its not small, try to increase the polling frequency in SFTP connector configuration. By default it is 1000ms. My guess is Mule requester is trying to read same file again before it completed streaming file first time.

Comment: You need to make sure that the file content is consumed. Can you try putting an Object to String transformer and check whether the file is deleted?

Comment: Thanks for your response Shamim! File size is only 1-2 kb. I have tried with Object to String transformer as well, but seems no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using File/SFTP/FTP component should be more careful on polling and FileAge( If needed for long size). Based on your Size of the payload, we need to increase the polling frequency.If the file size is large and the polling freq is less, it might read multiple times which end up in causing issues.

Also make sure your file is deleted once the file is read.

Below config working fine.

```
 <file:connector name="FileCon" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" fileAge="50" pollingFrequency="2000"/>
<flow name="removeFlow">
    <http:listener  config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"  path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['test']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <async doc:name="Async">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file://c:/in?connector=FileCon" timeout="30000" count="2" doc:name="Mule Requester" throwExceptionOnTimeout="true" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:/out" outputPattern="#[server.nanoTime()]#[function:uuid].txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </foreach>
    </async>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The requester does not on it own cycle through files in an SFTP path.  If you do not remove the first file from the path on the second access it will again get the same file.  Further, if you attempt to get a collection of files, it will get the same file over and over.  That second point, IMO is a flaw in the requester and should be corrected.  In any case, the result is you cannot get to the second file in the directory with the requester without consuming the first file to remove it from the path or if using a wildcard or regex filter renaming the file so it no longer matches you request criteria.

An option is to obtain a list of files and then build your request URL from the list of files, but this requires you to separately access the SFTP server to get this list, or simply know the names of the files you are looking for before you try to request them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Your reply on problem makes pretty sense!!

Comment: Sending the code. I have tried below things,
1) Input folder - File1 and File2.txt
2) Mule Requester - Issue I found with Mule is when I provided SFTP end point connector with File option as autoDelete=true, it doesn't reflect in config.xml file. SO - I have to manually make an entry.
3) I have removed the SFTP from For-Each and placed it with logger just as to check the file content.

Comment: <sftp:connector name="SFTP" validateConnections="true" duplicateHandling="addSeqNo"  doc:name="SFTP" autoDelete="true"/>
    <flow name="mulerequesterdemoFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="sftp://tester:tester@localhost/input?connector=SFTP" timeout="10000" returnClass="java.lang.String" count="5" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>

Comment: <logger message="Logger 1 ###########[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <foreach  doc:name="For Each">
            <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="22" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP" path="/out"/>
            <logger message="Payload &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>

Comment: An issue with autodelete which I have seen is the delete does not occur immediately especially when using streaming.  The flow does not delete until you are done with the resource.  If for instance you use an object-to-byte-array transformer, the entire stream in now in memory, so you have done something with the file and no longer need it.  The file can now be disposed of, so is deleted.  Without a step like this, or moving the file to another location, an action the flow recognizes as using the file, the delete is not executed.  Just logging does not seem enough to trigger the action.

Comment: It may take a bit of maneuvering to get the flow to work exactly as you would like, it has a definite learning curve and I fight it a bit each time. Something as simple as doing a transform on the file, or copying it to an archive location will trigger the delete.  If you loop on requests, once you have consumed all files you should get a null payload telling you there are no more to process.

Comment: Million Thanks for your response! It was indeed helpful! :)